# Python on Windows: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGWINCH'

Tags: python, windows, terminal, tui

I'm trying to run a program using [PyTermGUI](https://github.com/bczsalba/pytermgui/), but I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGWINCH'
```

I found [this](https://github.com/WoLpH/python-progressbar/issues/39) github issue for another TUI library for python, which says that Windows has no `signal.SIGWINCH`. I don't really know what `signal.SIGWINCH` is, but I'm wondering, is there any alternative or way to swap it out? Preferably without having to edit the module code. Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sigwinch is a signal for window resizing. You can not really swap it with anything.